# .Xauthority login loop

Tags: 20.04, login

My .Xauthority file doesn't look like it should? It's supposed to be `-rw------- 1` but mine has a bunch of extra r's (`-rw-r--r-- 1`). Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck in a login loop and I'm trying to fix it, hoping this is the problem but don't know how to fix it.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 klein klein   117 Jul  6 13:22  .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 klein klein     0 Jul  6 13:22  .xsession-errors
-rw------- 1 klein klein     0 Jul  6 13:22  .xsession-errors.old
drwx------ 8 klein klein  4096 Feb  7 19:10  .200m
klein # ~
```

Comment: Did this ever work? If so, what changed?

Comment: @Rinzwind how do you change it?  I have very little experience with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
chmod 600 .Xauthority
```

and it will be set to `-rw-------`. The login and it will continue.